# T-SQL Splitting String field by semi colon produces error XML parsing: line 1, character 49, illegal name character

Tags: sql-server, xml, string, t-sql, casting

I'm using SQL Server 2014. I have addresses stored like this as one large string in a column called `addr` in a table `tblAddress` (I have no control over this it is from a 3rd party supplier)

```
addr
--------------------------------------------------
1 Smith Street;My Old Town; Someplace;Pluto;
5 SmokeyStreet;Someoldtown;Someotherplace;;
7 Grove Hill; Someolder town;Someotherplace;Earth
```

I would like to extract it so it looks like the below split into 4 columns:

```
Addr1            Addr2           Addr3            Addr4
----------------------------------------------------------
1 Smith Street   My Old Town     Someplace        Pluto
5 SmokeyStreet   Someoldtown     Someotherplace
7 Grove Hill     Someolder town  Someotherplace   Earth
```

I've tried:

```
SELECT  
    CAST('<x>' + REPLACE([addr], ';', '</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML).value('/x[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') AS Addr1,
    CAST('<x>' + REPLACE([addr], ';', '</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML).value('/x[2]', 'nvarchar(50)') AS Addr2,
    CAST('<x>' + REPLACE([addr], ';', '</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML).value('/x[3]', 'nvarchar(50)') AS Addr3,
    CAST('<x>' + REPLACE([addr], ';', '</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML).value('/x[4]', 'nvarchar(50)') AS Addr4
FROM
    tblAddress;
```

But I keep getting an error:

> XML parsing: line 1, character 49, illegal name character

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: [I can't recreate this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=117da0d552a84865e26d127739a2fb55) with your sample data. Does your actual data contain illegal XML characters? If so, perhaps try [another method of splitting strings](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/09/t-sql-queries/split-strings)

Comment: Considering you have 4 parts, perhaps `PARSENAME` might be a better solution, assuming no part can be greater than 128 characters long, and contain no brackets (`[]`).

Comment: Possibly add in `CDATA` like this `CAST('<x><![CDATA[' + REPLACE([addr], ';', ']]></x><x><![CDATA[') + ']]></x>' AS XML)` it won't work for everything but it should deal with all printable characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than repeating calculations, you should consider using a CROSS APPLY once

**Example**

```
Select Pos1 = xDim.value('/x[1]' ,'varchar(150)')
      ,Pos2 = xDim.value('/x[2]' ,'varchar(150)')
      ,Pos3 = xDim.value('/x[3]' ,'varchar(150)')
      ,Pos4 = xDim.value('/x[4]' ,'varchar(150)')
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(A.addr,';','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml)) )B(xDim)
```

**Results**

```
Pos1             Pos2           Pos3            Pos4
1 Smith Street   My Old Town    Someplace       Pluto
5 SmokeyStreet   Someoldtown    Someotherplace  
7 Grove Hill     Someolder town Someotherplace  Earth
```